# clear previous screen after redirection ( clear back stack for fragment ) kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have onle activity and many fragments in my project. I have created splash screen fragment and redirecting to dashboard after 3 seconds. After I went to dashboard I pressed on back button which takes me back to the splash screen. It should not happen. how to clear previous screen after redirection. for example after successful payment we will be redirected to some screen and when we press back button it should not go to payment screen right?. I need to know how to clear the backstack in fragment not in activity [kotlin].

```
package spark.ar.assets

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import spark.ar.assets.databinding.FragmentSplashScreenBinding

class SplashScreen : Fragment() {

        private var binding: FragmentSplashScreenBinding?=null
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View {
            binding = FragmentSplashScreenBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)


            Handler().postDelayed({

                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashScreen_to_dashboard)



            }, 3000)


            return binding!!.root
        }

        override fun onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView()

            binding = null
        }




    }
```

This is my Splash screen fragment. how to clear after redirection.

I tried to add activity?.finish. It closes the whole app.

```
Handler().postDelayed({
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashScreen_to_dashboard)
                activity?.finish()
            }, 3000)
```

Answer (score 2):

to get what you want you must properly configure your action in nav_graph. If you click on action in design mode in navigation component you can see section 'popUpTo' and 'popUpToInclusive'. In 'popUpTo' you must set name of your nav_graph and set 'popUpToInclusive' to true. To get that effect you must also use NavDirections class when navigating(it is automatically generated by navigation component). In your case that will look like this:

```
val directions = SplashScreenDirections.actionSplashScreenToDashboard()
findNavController().navigate(directions)
```